# R to SAS Date Conversion

Tags: date, sas

I would like to convert the following R date calculation to SAS:

```
((as.POSIXlt(TRTDT) - as.POSIXlt(BRTHDT) +1)/365.25)
```

I read that I could use this: DATETIMEw.d but I don't know which numeric values I should use. My attempt would be:

```
(((TRTDT, DATETIMEw.d) - as.POSIXlt(BRTHDT, DATETIMEw.d) +1)/365.25)
```

Comment: Are your variables `TRTDT` and `BRTHDT` imported into SAS as dates or as datetimes? If they're dates they're probably 5-digit integers and if they're datetimes they should be much larger integers.

Comment: You need to confirm the type and format of your variable before we can answer that. If you're looking for a duration, look at the INTCK() which can handle, datetime, time, or date variables.

Comment: Hi! both dates for formatted as such: '2006-09-15'. In this case, would I do the following: ((INTCK(TRTDT) - INTCK(BRTHDT) +1)/365.25)?